# How can I update my Galaxy Tab to 2.3?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-tab

I bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab which has Android 2.2. I want to upgrade it to 2.3 but I don’t know how. I searched to find out a way to do so, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Which exact Galaxy Tab model do you have?  Samsung released 13 different models: http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/all-products  The official 2.3 upgrade may or may not be available for your specific model.

Answer (score 1):

You connect device to computer running samsung kies and do the damage with official gingerbread
All settings and databases will be lost or erased, so take care to make backup (if you know how to root then with titanium is best)

There is aftermarket Ice Cream Sandwich in development http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=807

Answer (score 0):

if u have the samsung galaxy tab p1010 (wifi only)

i found a firmware update to gingerbread 2.3.6 released in uk.

im in south africa i installed in on my tab it worked perfect problems.

but one thing if u do this u will lose ur warrenty well atleast i was told i would but hey it worked perfect...and till now there hasnt been a update in south africa so i did it.

http://www.sammobile.com/

register and login

click firmware

type-tablet

os-android

model-pick ur model if listed

as i said i picked a uk release